# "Down for" something vs. "Up for" something?

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs, colloquialisms

Is there any difference between someone saying they're "down for" something as opposed to being "up for" something?

For example:

> I'm totally up for ice cream tonight!

vs.

> I'm totally down for ice cream tonight!

Comment: It's usually *I'm down **with*** = "I am in agreement with". Your usage may be influenced by forms such as *"Put me down for ice-cream"* - when someone is making a (potentially metaphorical) list of what different people want/think.

Comment: Not true at all. "I'm Down for Whatever" is a hit song by Kelly Rowland, also see lyrics from a Drake song.

Comment: Perhaps the **down** form is newer and has simply taken on the same meaning?

Comment: I would say so, yes. I don't think I've ever actually heard your second usage (presumably *you* have, or you wouldn't be asking about it here). I think there's no question but that the "standard" version is "up", and it's unlikely any significant number of native speakers would use *both* versions (with different meanings). It may be relevant to ask yourself how often you hear them both (in particular, how often you hear them *without* the word ***totally***).

Comment: I would say "down with" is for saying you agree with/approve of something, whereas "up for" means you would be interested in doing something. So "I feel like some jazz music" - " I'm down with that" (ie, I'm fine with [approve of your idea of] hearing some jazz music), or "I'm up for that" (ie, I would like to hear some jazz music).